# Delete one event from recurring event Android Calendar

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-calendar

I`m using EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin for my app.I`m adding a daily event for 10 years. Example , my daily event is from 30.06.2015 until 30.06.2025. If i set interval to delete to be 02.07.2015-03.07.2015 (1 event from series) all event dissappear. I search for issues in plugin , but i didn't figure it out which is the problem. This is method from plugin.

```
 - public boolean deleteEvent(Uri eventsUri, long startFrom, long
   startTo, String title, String location) {
       //startFrom = startDate
       //startTo = endDate
       ContentResolver resolver = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
       Event[] events = fetchEventInstances(title, location,startFrom, startTo);      
       int nrDeletedRecords = 0;
       if (events != null) {
         for (Event event : events) {
           Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, Integer.parseInt(event.eventId));
              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "event.recurring: "+event.recurring);
           nrDeletedRecords = resolver.delete(eventUri,null,null);
         }
       }
       return nrDeletedRecords > 0;   }
```

FetchEventsInstances return perfect the result .. If date is set for 2 days .. number of events will be 2. I don`t know why all events are dissappear if only one event is found.If something is not clear I can offer more details. Can someone help me?